How do I clean up a remote drive using a recordset?
I have a sorted record set ("NewTbl") of the contents of a remote disk drive. This shows a great number of duplicated files and other anomalies. The record set holds the file name, its location on the disk and file type (extension). This allows me to assemble a string that should allow me to correctly identify any particular file. Using the Kill command I would be able to eliminate the duplicates. Generally speaking I'm OK with the logic of selecting the file I'm after but not so hot on the link to the disk using the available information. The code I've got together ( that doesn't work is below). The line it fails on is
fl.Name = ThsHm & ThsFl & "." & ThsExt
returning error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method".
Option Compare Database

Sub CleanUp()
    Dim fl As Object
    Set fl = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim NewTbl As DAO.Recordset
    Set NewTbl = db.OpenRecordset("Sorted", dbOpenDynaset)
    
    Dim ThsFl As String
    Dim NxtFl As String
    Dim ThsHm As String
    Dim NxtHm As String
    Dim ThsExt As String
    Dim NxtExt As String
    Dim ThsSz As String
    Dim NxtSz As String
    
    Dim FRED As Variant
    
    NewTbl.MoveFirst
    ThsFl = NewTbl("File").Value
    ThsHm = NewTbl("Home").Value
    ThsExt = NewTbl("Ext").Value
    ThsSz = CStr(NewTbl("KB Size").Value)
    NewTbl.MoveNext
    NxtFl = NewTbl("File").Value
    NxtHm = NewTbl("Home").Value
    NxtExt = NewTbl("Ext").Value
    NxtSz = CStr(NewTbl("KB Size").Value)
    NewTbl.MovePrevious
    
    If ThsHm = "F:\" And NxtHm = "F:\" Then
        fl.Name = ThsHm & ThsFl & "." & ThsExt
        Kill fl
    End If
    
End Sub


fl has been set as FileSystemObject, which you don't need and don't use in this procedure. And it doesn't have a .Name property, hence the error.
VBA Kill only takes a string (full path) as argument. So this would work:
    strFullPath = ThsHm & ThsFl & "." & ThsExt
    Kill strFullPath 

Your logic before that seems strange. The procedure will only ever process the first record of the table.
I would expect a loop over the recordset, like
Do While Not NewTbl.EOF
    ' ... process current file
    NewTbl.MoveNext
Loop


Thank you Andre. Yes you're absolutely right my logic was "off" but I will end up needing a lot more and it will need looping through 'NewTbl' quite a few times to clean up this mess and a lot more 'If ... then..' controls while stripping the deleted lines out of 'NewTbl' so I still have a long way to go. Again thank you for this bit of guidance.

If answer resolves issue, please mark accepted.
